# child_changed has no ref in firebase

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have many posts in the screen, and I also have this to check updates in realtime:

```
var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value).orderByKey();

post.on("child_changed", function(snap) {
    var changedPost = snap.val(); // what I changed only.
    console.log(snap.key); // null
    console.log("The updated post title is " + changedPost.titulo);
});

// I also use post to foreach posts using post.once("value" ...
```

The problem is, the return is only what I changed, if I change post title, it will return only the title, I have no snap.key to get the reference to update. any ideas how to solve this?

edit --------------------------------------------

the full code:

```
var Ref2 = firebase.database().ref('/Feed/' + "-idownner").limitToLast(10);

    Ref2.once('value', async function(snapshot) {
        const promises = []
        snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
            var value = subChild.val();

            value = value.postID;

            var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value).orderByKey();

post.on("child_changed", function(snap) {
    var changedPost = snap.val(); // what I changed only.
    console.log(snap.key); // null
    console.log("The updated post title is " + changedPost.titulo);
});

            promises.push(new Promise((res, rej) => {
                post.once('value', function(snapshot2) {

                    var obj = Object.assign(snapshot2.val(), { key: snapshot2.key });

                    res(obj);
                });
            }));
        });
        const postsArray = await Promise.all(promises);
        setPosts(prevPosts => {
            return [
                ...prevPosts,  
                ...Object.keys(postsArray).reverse().map(key => ({
                    key: key, ...postsArray[key] 
                }))
            ];
        });
    });
```

and my json:

```
{
  "Feed" : {
    "-idownner" : {
      "-M5XDPj_TGklk9Kw3YDo" : {
        "postID" : "-M5XDPj_TGklk9Kw3YDo"
      },
      "-M5XDTy1BovVNP2Vr6Tz" : {
        "postID" : "-M5XDTy1BovVNP2Vr6Tz"
      },
      "-M5XDUXYMUciF_Lfg6ec" : {
        "postID" : "-M5XDUXYMUciF_Lfg6ec"
      },
      "-M5XDVdmASSreXTH1zuF" : {
        "postID" : "-M5XDVdmASSreXTH1zuF"
      },
      "-M5XDWPwa_oq_xkFNQtv" : {
        "postID" : "-M5XDWPwa_oq_xkFNQtv"
      },
      "-M5XDWvCdjNDERvsHLYG" : {
        "postID" : "-M5XDWvCdjNDERvsHLYG"
      }
      }
    }
 },
   "posts" : {
    "-M5XDPj_TGklk9Kw3YDo" : {
      "img" : "img/",
      "timestamp" : 1587564622097,
      "titulo" : "title 1",
      "user" : "root"
    },
    "-M5XDTy1BovVNP2Vr6Tz" : {
      "img" : "img/",
      "timestamp" : 1587564635906,
      "titulo" : "title 1",
      "user" : "root"
    },
    "-M5XDTy1BovVNP2Vr6Tz" : {
      "img" : "img/",
      "timestamp" : 1587564639313,
      "titulo" : "title 1",
      "user" : "root"
    },
    "-M5XDUXYMUciF_Lfg6ec" : {
      "img" : "img/",
      "timestamp" : 1587564641641,
      "titulo" : "title 1",
      "user" : "root"
    },
    "-M5XDVdmASSreXTH1zuF" : {
      "img" : "img/",
      "timestamp" : 1587564643970,
      "titulo" : "title 1",
      "user" : "root"
    },
    "-M5XDWPwa_oq_xkFNQtv" : {
      "img" : "img/",
      "timestamp" : 1587564646214,
      "titulo" : "title 1",
      "user" : "root"
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you're describing is not how the API is supposed to work, nor how it always works when I use it. Every `snap` should have a `key` value in your example, and `snap.val()` should the entire node as it exists after the change. Can you set up a reproduction on a site like jsbin, so that I can have a look?

Comment: The combination of reading `/posts/$postid` with a `child_*` event is suspicious though. Are you sure you should not use `on("value", ...`? If not, can you edit your question to include the JSON at `posts` (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for late reply. I edited my question, add there the full code and json. I get postsIDs from `feed` and "join" the `posts` with foreach. I use on because I also use once in the code, with the same query, to get results in the feed without appending itens again after it loads (with on value it was appending all posts again if any changes). Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: This `var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value).orderByKey();

post.on("child_changed", function(snap) {` looks wrong to me. I'm pretty sure you should be using `on("value"` or `once("value"` to load the individual posts.